# Custom placeholders/tags for dynamic content in a Word template

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, wordml

I have a web application (ASP.NET C#) where I would like the users to be able to upload word templates (essentially word document with predefined set of tags serving as placeholders). Part of the complication is I want to allow for using loops as well. Finally I want to be able to parse the XML and replace the placeholders with content fetched from the database. 
For example a conceptual template may be:

```
Name: <firstName> <lastName>
Phone Numbers:
<for-each:phoneNumber>
Region Code: <regionCode>
Number: <number>
</end:for-each>
```

Are there any existing solutions that address this issue? Has anyone tried to achieve this or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've documented the approach to this that I have devised at opendope.org

It is based on CustomXML databinding (not to be confused with the stuff at issue in the i4i patent farce), extendedto allow loops.

For a proof of concept demo, see www.fabdocx.com

There isn't an OpenXML SDK C# implementation yet so far as I am aware, but you could convert the equivalent Java code.